How to open modal based on TempData value
I need to popup a model warning box based on conditions determined in controller code.  I load a warning message into temp data aand am trying to force the modal to open when text exists.
It doesn't open.  Code below:
type here<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ('@TempData["WarningText"] != "" || @TempData["WarningText"]" != null) {
            {
              $("#GenericWarningModal").modal('show');
            }
    });
</script>
<!-- Modal -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Warning", "Generic", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="modal fade" id="GenericWarningModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="warningModalTitle" data-bs-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="warningModalLongTitle">Confirm Tee Time Removal</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @ViewBag.WarningText
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" id="modalProceed"  class="btn btn-primary">Proceed</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


Please tag your Bootstrap version. Also tag JavaScript, jQuery, and whatever technology correlates to TempData.

The problem was how to access TempData from javascript.
This worked:
    var work = ('@(TempData["WarningText"])');
    if (work.length > 0) {
        $("#GenericWarningModal").modal('show');
    }

